# How to change the system folders (Pictures, Movies etc)

Tags: finder

It used to be possible (before Big Sur I think) to rename and remap the system folders (Pictures, Movies etc). What I am trying to do is move the folders to Dropbox like this:

`sudo mv ~/Documents ~/Documents_old`

`ln -s ~/Dropbox/Pictures ~/Pictures`

When I do that I get the following message:

`mv: rename /Users/neilthompson/Pictures to /Users/neilthompson/Pictures_old: Operation not permitted`

I know that it used to be possible because [I have been doing it since 2014](https://www.spokenlikeageek.com/2014/05/27/a-potentially-dangerous-experiment/) but just moved to a brand new machine and now it doesn't work.

Anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: You may have to give whole disk permission and files and folders permission to terminal .. [I had a similar problem trying to move the iPhone backups folder].  System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab.

Comment: Yes that was exactly it. I needed to give full disk access to Terminal to make it work. Do you want to answer the question so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give full disk access to Terminal to make it work - those permissions seem to have changed in Big Sur.  Go System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy and grant the permission to Terminal.  Even files that look like you have full control over them (based on unix permissions) can be impacted.